# Wrong X and Y touchscreen axis after screen rotation on Raspberry Pi 3B+ and Raspberry Pi zero w

Tags: raspbian, display, pi-zero-w, pi-3b+

I can successful rotate the screen with `display_rotate=1` (and `display_rotate=0` to return back to landscape mode).

But, I cannot get the X and Y axis to work correctly after the rotation.

How can I change the X and Y axis so the touch screen works correctly after the screen rotation?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `lcd_rotate=1` instead? Source: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=120785

Comment: lcd_rotate=1 does not work at all.